# Change XML value using Code Synthesis c++

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

I need to change some values of an existing XML using Code Synthesis in c++.

For example i have this:

```
<person>
  <name>"Paul"</name>
</person>
```

Now i need to change it to "Chris".

I have used several time Code Synthesis for parsing but never to write into a XML.

p.s Yes i've compiled my XSD with "Generate Serialization" option.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ class that was generated out of the schema type for the person element probably has a member function for setting the name:

```
void name(const ::xml_schema::string& s);
```

You would then be able to change the name to Chris like this:

```
person.name("Chris");
```

You could find more information in the C++/Tree Mapping Getting Started Guide. See the chapter 2.5: [Adding Serialization](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2.5).

There is also a small code example that reads in an XML file into the Codesynthesis data model, then modifies some values, and finally serializes it to back to XML. See the [library example](http://scm.codesynthesis.com/?p=xsd/xsd.git;a=blob;f=examples/cxx/tree/library/driver.cxx;hb=HEAD).

Comment: nice.Thank you, what i was missing was that if i need to actually change my xml file, i need to load it again to stringstream and then write it to the file. Although i was manipulating data of my xml object correctly!

Comment: Great that it now works. Instead of first writing to std::stringstream you could write directly to the file with std::ofstream. For instance, see the line `std::ofstream ofs (argv[1]);` in chapter 2.5: [Adding Serialization](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2.5)